# hibernate validator nested class with xml mappings

Tags: xml, hibernate, jakarta-ee

Very corner case, and googling around does not seem to help.

I have to use xml validation (generated code) and the scenario is similar to:

```
 // This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML
 Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, v2.2.4 

 ...

 @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) @XmlType(name = "xxx", propOrder
 = { ... }) @XmlRootElement(name = "xxx") public class Class01DTO
     implements Serializable { ...
     @XmlElement(required = true)
     protected BetslipDTO.SlipPlacement slipPlacement;

     ...

     @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
     @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { ...
     })
     public static class Class02
         implements Serializable
     {

         private final static long serialVersionUID = ...;

         protected String stringToValidate;


     }

 }
```

I am not confident on how to validate "stringToValidate". I have a constraints-mapping.xml with something like:

```
<bean class="com.etc.Class01DTO.Class02">
    <field name="stringToValidate">
        <constraint annotation="javax.validation.constraints.NotNull">
        </constraint>
    </field>
</bean>
```

That just generates an error. Different combinations have been tried, without a result. Has anyone faced the same case?
I assume it is clear that the code is generated, so cannot use the option of having annotation based validation...

Error is similar to the following when doing a build
...

```
  shouldValidateSpringContext(com.etc.TestBetSpringContext): Error creating bean with name 'validatorFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [spring/bet-service.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000065: Unable to load class: com.etc.Class01DTO.Class02.
```

Comment: I don't think anyone is able to help unless you specify the error details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to specify a nested classname, you should rather use `com.etc.Class01DTO$Class02`, after compilation of those classes, take a look at target directory, you'll find that all nested classes are compiled into separate files with `$` in their names.

Comment: Totally yes. Eclipse on rolling over gave "com.etc.Class01DTO.Class02" helping me forget the actual notation/class name...